# Need help in web config file

Tags: asp.net, configuration

I am facing problem when i am creating new user,using CreateUserWizard control.I have added  in connection string :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BankingTransaction"
      connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Bank.mdf;integrated security=True;User Instance=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

After adding this connection string in web.config file, when i am running the application i am able create the New user Sign up details. But when i am adding the following code in web.config file i am getting error "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'." the code is:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="BankingTransaction" 
      enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
      applicationName="/"
      requiresUniqueEmail="true"
      passwordFormat="Clear"
      minRequiredPasswordLength="3"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
      passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
      name="DefaultMembershipProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Please somebody help me whats wrong with my above red highlighted code.

Thanks,
Masum

Comment: Please chek [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/ac0770af-a781-4558-9f2f-f8bea17665be/) and [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx) and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: Hi Mr.ScarletGarden yea its yesterday's question since yesterday i am hanging out with this problem could not get the exact root of error.

Comment: I remember your question, look below for my suggestion. hope it helps.
By the way, if you update your question instead of asking new one people can see the suggestions that helped and not helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should register your new database with [ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool (Aspnet_regsql.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx) tool.